# sincedb_write_interval is not working in ELK

Tags: elastic-stack

I am doing offline analysis of the logs from previous days. Elasticsearch and logstash version used is 2.3.1

My input file:

```
      path => "/opt/logs/test/*"
     sincedb_path => "/opt/logs/.sincedb" 
     sincedb_write_interval => 10  
      start_position => "beginning"
```

I see the sincedb file is created only when the last log line is reached. And whenever the logstash file is stopped in between, the log parsing is started from the beginning instead of the position where it was stopped. This causes duplicate entries in kibana.

I assume the sincedb should write at interval of every 10sec to the file(as specified in my input). And if the logstash is stopped for any reason and restarted it should continue from the previous stoped position. Is there some more code to be added or the sincedb file is created only at the end of the file? Please suggest how to avoid duplicate parsing.